# Laravel edit page does not call CSS and JS when on a server

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, laravel-8

I made an edit page for my application which is accessible via the index. I have a master.blade.php file that contains all the references for scripting and the CSS links. and every page calls this master page to make use of the Nav bar, heading and the CSS/JS. The edit page does not seem to call this and on the console it shows `404 not found` for these CSS and JS files when I pushed this project on a server. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong

I have changed the routing of the CSS/JS files to route correctly and that calls correctly everywhere else but this page.

Here is a sample of my paths:

```
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

this is in my master page, so in my other pages I call:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
```

Comment: "*Does anyone know what I am doing wrong*" How can we know that without any code sample? You definitely need to debug it yourself with the inspection tool of your browser and I'm quite sure that is caused by some typo in your path. Without minimal details about your structure and generated pahs we're even not able to *try to guess* what the issue is. Show us at least one path which isn't found and also tell us the exact URL of the page where the problem occurs.

Comment: sorry about that @biesior. I was not sure what to include, Let me put a path

Comment: Don't be sorry, good you have the will to * cooperate* ;) as mentioned previously also tell us the exact URL (from the address bar) of the missing assets like this CSS and page where it occurs (domain name can be fake), so we can compare like: my CSS is at `domain.tld/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css` and the problem occurs on page `domain.tld/path/to/my/edit/page`

Comment: @biesior okay so my page is `testapp\public\assets\css\bootstrap.min.css` and the page it errors in is  `domain.tdl/testapp/energys-edit/1042`. where 1042 is the id of the record I am editing

Comment: @biesior i see in the console that the js and css files are being read from `testapp\energys-edit\public\assets\css\bootstrap.min.css`... thats not supposed to happen rather it should read from the path above

Comment: So you have clearly the wrong path. A path starting with `../` is **relative** so the browser tries to find it in one folder *higher* from your position, use absolute pathstarting from the root, with slash at the beginning like `<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />` that one should point to asset which is available at url, `http://domain.tld/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css`, verify it yet and fix if required.

Comment: @biesior, I had the issue of it not calling the paths at all without `/public` bring used at the start... what I did though was make an `energy-edits` folder and I put a public folder in there and it works... do you think that's okay?

Comment: solved: caused by path error

Comment: "*I did though was make an energy-edits folder and I put a public*" - nope, adding a copy of your assets in the `energy-edits/public` folder is not a solution. You need to use the absolute paths for existing assets once. For others: this was caused by the wrong path and now OP already fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel, best way to import any asset, is using asset function in your blade file:

```
asset('path to css')
```

This is work for images, CSS and JS files, and other files to import into a blade or HTML.
just upload your files into "public" folder like this folders scaffolding:

```
---- public
---- ---- css
---- ---- ---- bootstrap.min.css
```

and use asset function like this:

```
<link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I hope this response being useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

use asset function like this

```
<link href="{{asset('path')}}" rel="stylesheet" />
```